# NestJS - How to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header for Response

Tags: javascript, angular, nestjs, saml, nestjs-passport

I am trying to set the Response header in NestJS, but keep getting the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://companyName.okta.com/app/companyName_imentorlocalhost_1/exk1hp5ht4vrEzqGg0h8/sso/saml?SAMLRequest=nVPLct... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I tried setting the header in the controller, but that didn't work:

`auth.controller`:

```
@UseGuards(SamlAuthGuard)
@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
@Get('box-utility-service/auth/login')
login(@Request() req): any {}

@UseGuards(SamlAuthGuard)
@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
@Post('imentor-service/login/callback')
oktaCallback (@Request() req, @Response() res: Response): any {
    return this.authService.login(req);
}
```

Also tried setting the header in an interceptor.  Didn't work either:

`header.interceptor.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeaderInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(() => {
        const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Here's my `main.ts`, where I enable CORS:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'my-secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false
    }),
  );

  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: [ 'Accept', 'Accept-Version', 'Content-Type', 'Api-Version', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With',
      'Authorization' ],
    origin: [ 'https://companyName.okta.com', 'http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost' ],
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: [ 'API-Token-Expiry' ]
  });

  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new HeaderInterceptor());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And here is my `saml-strategy.ts` file, where I define the `Passport` strategy to be SAML:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
const nconf = require('nconf');
import { get } from 'lodash';
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class Saml2Strategy extends PassportStrategy(SamlStrategy, 'saml') {
  users = [];

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private usersService: UsersService
  ) {
    super({
      issuer: nconf.get('saml:issuer'),
      path: nconf.get('saml:path'),
      entryPoint: nconf.get('saml:entryPoint'),
      cert: nconf.get('saml:cert')
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    const oeid = payload.nameID;
    let user;

    if (oeid) {
      try {
        let userADData = await this.authService.validateUser(oeid);
        userADData = get(userADData, 'data.data[0]');

        if (userADData) {
          user = await this.usersService.findOrCreate(userADData);
        }

        return user;
      } catch (err) {
        return err;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea of what's going on?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks. Yeah, that's what I followed to set it up in the project, and passed some `options` to `app.enableCors` in `main.ts` above based on https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options.  Though I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the way I was handling the OKTA login workflow.  I was redirecting an XHR request (which OKTA didn't like, as it was missing the required header to do so), and was getting an error code.